# Undefined variable: _ENV in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, error, vendor, undefined-variable

**I get this error on frontend:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: _ENV in
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php
>   on line 67
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: _ENV in
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php
>   on line 67 Exception: Notice: Undefined variable: _ENV in
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Processor/EnvironmentPlaceholder.php
>   on line 57 in
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Processor/EnvironmentPlaceholder.php(57):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined varia...',
>   '/home/jacstoreo...', 57, Array) #1
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/PreProcessorComposite.php(35):
>   Magento\Config\Model\Config\Processor\EnvironmentPlaceholder->process(Array)
>
> ## 2 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(60):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\PreProcessorComposite->process(Array) #3
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #4
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(326):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #5
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(249):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->readData() #6
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(177):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadScopeData('stores',
>   'jacstoreonlinee...') #7
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(142):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->getWithParts('stores/jacstore...')
>
> ## 8 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131):
>
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('stores/jacstore...') #9
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(80):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'stores/jacstore...') #10
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/Logger/Handler/Debug.php(63):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('dev/debug/debug...', 'stores')
>
> ## 11 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(31):
>
> Magento\Developer\Model\Logger\Handler\Debug->isHandling(Array) #12
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(344):
>   Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #13
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Monolog.php(48):
>   Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'Notice: Undefin...', Array) #14
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(707):
>   Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog->addRecord(400, 'Notice: Undefin...',
>   Array) #15
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
>   Monolog\Logger->error('Notice: Undefin...') #16
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 17 {main}

**I get this error in the backend:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: _ENV in
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php
>   on line 67
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: _ENV in
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php
>   on line 67 Exception: Notice: Undefined variable: _ENV in
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Processor/EnvironmentPlaceholder.php
>   on line 57 in
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Processor/EnvironmentPlaceholder.php(57):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined varia...',
>   '/home/jacstoreo...', 57, Array) #1
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/PreProcessorComposite.php(35):
>   Magento\Config\Model\Config\Processor\EnvironmentPlaceholder->process(Array)
>
> ## 2 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(60):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\PreProcessorComposite->process(Array) #3
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #4
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(326):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #5
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(218):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->readData() #6
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(168):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default')
>
> ## 7 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(142):
>
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->getWithParts('default/web/url...')
>
> ## 8 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131):
>
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/url...') #9
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(80):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/url...') #10
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/MutableScopeConfig.php(36): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/url/use_sto...',
>   'default', NULL) #11
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Request/StorePathInfoValidator.php(70):
>   Magento\Framework\App\MutableScopeConfig->getValue('web/url/use_sto...')
>
> ## 12 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(99): Magento\Store\App\Request\StorePathInfoValidator->getValidStoreCode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 13 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(157): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId() #14
>
> /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore(NULL) #15
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(30):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL) #16
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49):
>   Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL) #17
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(69):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores',
>   NULL) #18
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/Logger/Handler/Debug.php(63):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('dev/debug/debug...', 'stores')
>    #19 /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(31):
>   Magento\Developer\Model\Logger\Handler\Debug->isHandling(Array) #20
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(344):
>   Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #21
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/Monolog.php(48):
>   Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'Notice: Undefin...', Array) #22
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(707):
>   Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog->addRecord(400, 'Notice: Undefin...',
>   Array) #23
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
>   Monolog\Logger->error('Notice: Undefin...') #24
>   /home/jacstoreonline/public_html/magento/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 25 {main}

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: how do you get this error?

Comment: I have no idea :S i just turned on the computer one day and went to the site, and thats what happened i did not even touch the files that are mentioned in the log

Comment: I cant see frontend nor backend thats what i see on each end.